Excel: preserve hyperlink to the cell in the current sheet after copying the sheet
I have an Excel file (containing Sheet1 only), with hyperlink formula in cell B3 (=HYPERLINK("#'Sheet1'!A1","link")) pointing to cell A1 of Sheet1. Then I copy Sheet1 (so have now Sheet1 and Sheet1(2)). Desired result: hyperlink formula in B2 of (a new) Sheet2 pointing to cell A1 of a new Sheet1(2) after clicking (by default it is pointing to cell A1 of old Sheet1). How can I improve the formula (=HYPERLINK("#'Sheet1'!A1","link")) so that it is pointing to the cell A1 of the new (current) spreadsheet Sheet1(2) (=I would like to have a (relative) reference to the current sheet robust to copying of sheet instead of (absolute) reference to the initial sheet)? Many thanks in advance!

You need to exclude sheet's name from the hyperlink:
=HYPERLINK("#A1","link")


rotabor's shorter method works well.

As rotabor commented, you could

Define a name in Name Manager for the cell, for example target1=Sheet1!$A$1, with scope set to Sheet1
Use this in hyperlink as =HYPERLINK("#target1","link")
When copying the sheet, the name also will be created scoped to the new sheet, so the hyperlink will work locally



You could try
=LET(
    n, CELL("filename"),
    sh, REPLACE(n, 1, FIND("]", n), ""),
    HYPERLINK("#'" & sh & "'!A1", "link")
)


Another sophisticated way is to define worksheet-scoped Name TargetA1=Sheet1!$A$1, then HYPERLINK("#TargetA1","link2A1").

Hash symbol explanation. In formulas above it means a fragment in the current workbook/worksheet.

Many thanks for your replies/comments!

You're most welcome!
